# Laravel pass current user id to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

So basically I am sending a form, within this form I have 3 fields. I need another field for user_id. So I've decided to do it through backend instead of having it in HTML since people can manipulate it.

`<form action="{{ route('events.store', Auth::user() ) }}" method="post">`

But whenever I `dd($request)` in `events.store` It shows me this:

```
+query: ParameterBag {#59 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      1 => null
    ]
  }
```

This would be right, since I have id 1.

To prove this, I've used devtools to manipulate the form action and put a custom value of my own named "testing". Like this:

`<form action="http://192.168.1.14/public/calendar?testing" method="post"">`

This would output

```
+query: ParameterBag {#59 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "testing" => null
    ]
  }
```

How can I access the id? And how can I make it unmanipulatible?

Question 2, how can I use that field to store it? I'm doing it like this:

```
Event::create(
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'event_date' => 'required'
    ])
);
```

I'd like it to be maybe like this:

```
'user_id' => $request->user_id
```

And also have it to be required

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could just use auth()->user()->id in your controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the currently logged in user, then it is much easier than passing it through a form or manually passing it in the URL.

You can use:

```
$request->id()

$request->user()->id

auth()->user()->id

auth()->id()
```

All return the current user id, just make sure that your route is `auth` protected, meaning you use the `auth` middleware for it.

-- ADDITION

I would add a relationship in the User model for the events, I guess it is one to many, so this:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}
```

Then in your controller, you can store it like this:

```
auth()->user()->events()->create($request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'event_date' => 'required'
    ]));
```

Comment: Hey! That worked, I was wondering if you could help with the second part, how do I fill the ```user_id``` field in using ```Task::create($request->validate([])```

Also, it is protected yes.

Comment: Amazing, it worked. Thanks! Also, the scecond one didnt work. But the ```auth()->user()->events()->create``` did.

Comment: I would prefer the first one anyway. I couldn't test, so I will delete the second one just to not confuse someone else.